# OpenGL GLSL Binding Sampler for Fragment Shader

Tags: c++, opengl, 2d, glsl, fragment-shader

I am hoping to implement a shader on a 2D OpenGL application.  My plan is to render a scene to a framebuffer object, and then render that framebuffer object to the screen using a shader.

Here is the scene, which I have drawn to a framebuffer object, and then to the screen from there.  Using the arrow keys makes the moon move around (I am quite proud of it!)

[image: Screen 1]

However, when I try to render the framebuffer object to the screen using my shader program, I get this:

[image: Screen 2]

It is very sad.  This fragment shader is one which I got from a [tutorial](http://www.mbsoftworks.sk/index.php?page=tutorials&series=1&tutorial=9), and I'm sure the problem has to be with the Uniform Variables.

Here is the Fragment Shader:

```
#version 330

in vec2 texCoord;
out vec4 outputColor;

uniform sampler2D gSampler;

void main()
{
   outputColor = texture2D(gSampler, texCoord);
}
```

Here is how I set up the Uniform Variables:

```
gSampler = glGetUniformLocation(mProgramID, "gSampler");
glUniform1i(gSampler, GL_TEXTURE0);
```

Here is how I render the Framebuffer (fbo_texture) to the screen, using my shader program (mProgramID)

```
glBindFramebufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT,    0 ); 

glUseProgram(mProgramID);
glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + 0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, fbo_texture);

glBegin(GL_QUADS);x1= 0.0;x2= 400.0;y1= 0.0;y2 = 400.0;
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f); glVertex2f(x1, y1);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f); glVertex2f(x1, y2);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f); glVertex2f(x2, y2);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f); glVertex2f(x2, y1);

glEnd();glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

SDL_GL_SwapBuffers();
```

So my question is- What is the link between a texture and a sampler?  Do I need to render a textured quad, if the shader is already sampling the texture?  Why not just render a blank quad if the shader is texturizing it?

EDIT:  Here is the vertex shader:

```
void main()
{

    gl_TexCoord[0] = gl_MultiTexCoord0;
    gl_Position = ftransform();
}
```

Comment: You are mixing and matching fixed-function vertex functions with generic vertex attributes in your vertex shader. You either need to use `glVertexAttrib2f (...)` or re-write your shader to use `gl_MultiTexCoord0` and `gl_Vertex`. Actually, I just realized you have not even shown your vertex shader (that is a fragment shader using `in` and `out`)... can you add that to your question?

Comment: You're right, those IN and OUT lines are totally unnecessary, are they supposed to talk to the Vertex Shader?

Comment: Well, in the fragment shader, an `in` variable comes from the output of a vertex shader (or geometry/tessellation evaluation in newer versions of GLSL), `out` refers to the color output. My comment was more along the lines that if your ***vertex*** shader is using `in` or `attribute` variables, then you should not be using fixed-function vertex functions. But now that you have shown your vertex shader, I can see that it is not necessary. But you do need to match up `gl_TexCoord[0]` in the fragment shader.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's indeed a problem with how you set the uniform value for the sampler:

```
gSampler = glGetUniformLocation(mProgramID, "gSampler");
glUniform1i(gSampler, GL_TEXTURE0);
```

The value you need to set for the uniform is the index of the texture unit, not the corresponding enum value. Since you are using texture unit 0 in this case, you need to replace the `glUniform1i()` call by:

```
glUniform1i(gSampler, 0);
```

Comment: OHHH It works now!  The shader is really rendering it!  So that means that my glActiveTexture was set to 0, but the GL_TEXTURE0 is something else so it didnt find the texture.  Great!!